# Connecting a 5m 300 LED ws2812b LED strip to Raspberry Pi controller using single power input point

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4, neopixel

I have a 5m ws2812b LED strip and am trying to operate it using neopixels python module from Pi4. I'm powering the strip using 5V 20A 100W SMPS to open end of red and white wires of strip directly, also data (GPIO18), ground of Pi to 3-pin connectors using jumper cables. The lights don't glow up.
When I tried the same with 1m strip and 5V 3A adaptor, it worked perfectly.

Can anyone help me with this